Connection => "access_control"
is there any possibility for an admin to prevent a DAG from using a connection ID in Airflow?
Purpose : Prevent a developer from using a specific connection.
Example : with a connection "CONN01_super_confidential" I want only DAGs of "team_a" to be able to use this connection.
This granurity of right can be manageable by Airflow?
